# iron-list overlap paper cards after loading image from network

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-starter-kit, progressive-web-apps

I am using polymer `iron-list` with paper-card but the problem is all cards are overlap until change the orientation of device. 
How do i call `notifyResize()` of `iron-list` after image loading of `paper-card`.

```
 <iron-list items="[[data.data]]" as="item" scroll-target="document">
        <template>

            <div style="margin-top: 20px">

                <!--Card with header image-->
                <paper-card heading="Emmental" image="http://placehold.it/350x150/FFC107/000000" alt="Emmental">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <b>#[[index]] - [[item.category]]</b>
                        <p>[[item.heading]]</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-actions">
                        <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
                        <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
                    </div>
                </paper-card>

            </div>


        </template>
    </iron-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will run the `notifyResize()` method on the `iron-sort` element itself.

```
<iron-list items="[[data.data]]" as="item" scroll-target="document">
  ...
</iron-list>
document.querySelector('iron-list').notifyResize()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across the same issue developing my app and here's the solution I came up with, however depending on what style's you've applied to the iron-list your mileage may vary.

```
Polymer
({
  is: "tt-itinerary-list",
  properties:
  {
    list:
    {
      type: Array,
      value:[]
    }
  },
  init: function(data)
  {
    var instance = this;
    instance.set("list", data);

    instance.async(instance._monitorImageLoad, 200);
  },
  _monitorImageLoad: function()
  {
    var instance = this;

    var images = instance.querySelectorAll("paper-card .header img");

    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i)
    {
      (function(image)
      {
        // if image is already loaded
        if(image.complete)
        {
          instance._resizeList();
        }
        // wait for the image to load
        else
        {
          image.addEventListener
          (
            "load",
            instance._resizeList.bind(instance)
          )
        }
      })(images[i]);
    }
  },
  _resizeList: function()
  {
    var instance = this;
    instance.$.list.fire("iron-resize");
  }
});
```

Basically what happens is that we call the `init` function whenever we get new data. Then we asynchronously call the `_monitorImageLoad` function which iterates over all of the images in the `paper-card` headers and then monitors their loading process. If an image has already loaded we just notify `iron-list` that in needs to resize (via the `iron-resize` event) otherwise we wait for it load before notify.